# Improve code readability of a Python lambda expression with condition

Tags: python, lambda, readability, code-readability

First of all I do not know if these types of questions are appropriate in stackoverflow.

I have the following dict:

```
file_dict = {"asda_20221003:ada":1, "scdfws_20221104eaf2we":5, "iasndcfiopsadn":9}
```

The key values of the dict always contains a date with the format %Y%m%d, what i want i to obtain the value for the key that have the highest date.

What I have done is the following:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(file_dict.items(), key=lambda t: datetime.strptime(re.findall("\d{8}",t[0])[0], "%Y%m%d") if len(re.findall("\d{8}",t[0])) > 0 else datetime.min, reverse=True))
```

This expression works but it is unreadable. Is there any way in order to improve it?

what i would like is to asigne at some point `re.findall("\d{8}",t[0])` to a variable (for example date) and use this one for all the expression.

Something like this:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(file_dict.items(), key=lambda t: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y%m%d") if len(re.findall("\d{8}",t[0]) as x) > 0 else None, reverse=True))
```

I am also open for other ways to perform this operation

Comment: define a regular function?

Comment: Do the keys already sort correctly as strings?

Comment: `len(re.findall("\d{8}",t[0]) as x)` could be accomplished with an assignment expression `len(x := re.findall("\d{8}",t[0]))`.  I'm not sure it's more readable, but there it is.

Comment: Note that as of Python 3.7 dictionaries are guaranteed to retain the insertion order of the keys, so `OrderedDict()` can be replaced by `dict()` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compare list of strings and not compare datetimes.

As @Steven Rumbalski said: Note that as of Python 3.7 dictionaries are guaranteed to retain the insertion order of the keys, so `OrderedDict()` can be replaced by `dict()` in this example.

```py
OrderedDict(
    sorted(file_dict.items(),
           key=lambda t: re.findall(r"\d{8}", t[0]),
           reverse=True))

# OR
dict(
    sorted(file_dict.items(),
           key=lambda t: re.findall(r"\d{8}", t[0]),
           reverse=True))
```

Results:

```
OrderedDict([('scdfws_20221104eaf2we', 5),
             ('asda_20221003:ada', 1),
             ('iasndcfiopsadn', 9)])

# OR
{'scdfws_20221104eaf2we': 5, 'asda_20221003:ada': 1, 'iasndcfiopsadn': 9}
```

Comment: Python 3's `dict`s are insertion ordered by default as @Steven Rumbalski wrote

Comment: Yes, but @david.t_92 uses an OrderedDict, so I keep his choice. I don't know what he wants to do with this data afterwards that's why... Answer edited btw